# Load code in to website with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load this code in to my website with ajax? What will i do?

```
   <ul class="rounded">
                        <li><div id="card" class="quickflip-wrapper"><p id="cardText"></p></div>
                        </li></ul>            
                    <ul class="rounded">
                        <li><div class="right">Nästa</div>
                        </li></ul>


                       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.enormous.se/dev/mobile2/main/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
               <script type="application/javascript" src="http://m.drickspel.com/assets/js/olspelet.js"></script>
```

I used this code before but it doesn't work. The code above is in the content.php. When i load the content.php in my browser it work good but not on the site.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").load("content.php");
})
```

Here is the site: http://www.enormous.se/dev/mobile2/main/#vem

Comment: It's hard to help you debug with the code you provided, can you provide more?

Comment: Link to your actual site.

Comment: I post the link to my site. @AlexCheuk

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your page source, one issue is that you are not loading jQuery. You are loading a file named jquery.js that actually contains a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Exactly what i found too. This `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` as given in the example is not what is in the page.

Comment: 1) Check your console before posting here. 2) Include jQuery.

Comment: Well, that's why I said *one* issue... the rest is missing too, for example where is your load()? You'd better double check the whole page now.

Comment: Ooooh, before i post this subject i make some change. 
Sorry! But still not working.

Comment: I double checked and now it is working, I can see the content of your olspelet2.php in the page.